# Intuit anywhere API telling me that a field is required when it's already specified

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to create an invoice in QB for windows. Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Add xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/V2./RestDataFilter.xsd " RequestId="1836474224e142c9ad9b7dd6cb0eaa41" FullResponse="true">
  <OfferingId>ipp</OfferingId>
  <ExternalRealmId>596059545</ExternalRealmId>
  <Invoice>
    <Header>
      <TxnDate>2013-01-30</TxnDate>
      <DiscountAmt>0</DiscountAmt>
      <ARAccountName>Sales - Support and Maintenance</ARAccountName>
      <DiscountAccountName>Discounts/Refunds</DiscountAccountName>
      <DueDate>2013-02-17</DueDate>
      <Currency>USD</Currency>
      <CustomerId>4</CustomerId>
    </Header>
    <Line>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
      <UnitPrice>7.00</UnitPrice>
      <Desc>Follow-up Test, Instant for Person138-Org3 Person138-Org3</Desc>
    </Line>
  </Invoice>
</Add>
```

Here's the response:

```
-2001:  cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ARAccountName'. One of '{"http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":DiscountAccountId, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":DiscountAccountName, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":DiscountTaxable, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":TxnId}' is expected.
```

I don't understand, as I already have DiscountAccountName specified. I also tried to go with something more like the [create example](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Invoice) (same as above but with ARAccountName and DiscountAccountName removed) and got a similar response. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328867/does-xml-care-about-the-order-of-elements   relevant?

Comment: Hmm, it certainly makes me wonder. I'll try switching the order. Thanks Marc!

Comment: Yep, it was relevant. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intuit XML requests are validated by an XSD, and with XML validated by XSDs the *order of the tags you provide matters*.

That means that if the documentation (https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/Invoice) dictates that ARAccountName comes *before* DiscountAmt, then you *must* put ARAccountName before DiscountAmt.

Switch the order of your XML tags to match the order shown in the docs, and you'll be all set.