# XML in Go - how to take either tag and match it to the field of a struct?

Tags: xml, go

Is it feasible to match either tag of a XML file to the field of a struct in `encoding/xml` package in Go?

For example, in the following XML file:

```
<person>
    <food type="fruit" />
    <furniture type="refrigerator" />
    <food type="vegetable" />
    <food type="fruit" />
<person>
```

Can I get `food` and `furniture` within the same `person` field with the respective order?

So what I want to get is as follows:

```
main.Person{main.Food{Type:"fruit"}, main.Furniture{Type:"refrigerator"}, main.Food{Type:"vegetable"}, main.Food{Type:"fruit"}}
```

instead of

```
main.Person{Food:[]main.Food{main.Food{Type:"fruit"}, main.Food{Type:"vegetable"}, main.Food{Type:"fruit"}}, Furniture:[]main.Furniture{main.Furniture{Type:"refrigerator"}}}
```

This is because I have to take each item inside the `person` as chronological order, and the latter example sorts items only within each sub-tags. So I cannot know when the `furniture` tag happens in the latter, but can get in the former - 3rd in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly related to [Does XML care about the order of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328867/does-xml-care-about-the-order-of-elements) .

Basically, without an [XSD (XML Schema Definition)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)), you can't specify the order that XML elements are processed or presented.

If you process the XML with a valid XSD it may work.

Have a look at [go-xsd](https://github.com/metaleap/go-xsd).