# Preserving order of elements when converting XSD to Dataset to XML

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, xsd, dataset

I am loading an XSD file into an empty dataset, loading data into the dataset, and then writing an XML file with that dataset.

The problem is if the XSD has a sequence type that contains a mixture of simple types and complex types in random order. The XML generated will always create the simple types first (based on the table columns) and then the complex types (based on the child rows of the data table), which is of course failing validation against a sequence type.

Here is an example:

```
       var schemaString = @"<xs:schema xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" >
<xs:element name=""Person"">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name=""Ttl"" minOccurs=""0"">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base=""xs:string"">
            <xs:maxLength value=""4"" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
     <xs:element minOccurs=""0"" maxOccurs=""1"" name=""Address"">
       <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element minOccurs=""1"" maxOccurs=""4"" name=""Line_1"">
             <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base=""xs:string"">
               <xs:maxLength value=""35"" />
             </xs:restriction>
             </xs:simpleType>
           </xs:element>
           <xs:element minOccurs=""1"" maxOccurs=""4"" name=""Line_2"">
             <xs:simpleType>
               <xs:restriction base=""xs:string"">
                    <xs:maxLength value=""35"" />
                </xs:restriction>
             </xs:simpleType>
           </xs:element>
           <xs:element minOccurs=""0"" maxOccurs=""1"" name=""PostCode"">
             <xs:simpleType>
                 <xs:restriction base=""xs:string"">
                   <xs:maxLength value=""35"" />
                 </xs:restriction>
             </xs:simpleType>
           </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
      <xs:element name=""Fore"" maxOccurs=""2"">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base=""xs:string"">
            <xs:maxLength value=""35"" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name=""Sur"">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base=""xs:string"">
            <xs:maxLength value=""35"" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
     
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>";

        var schemaReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(schemaString));

        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXmlSchema(schemaReader);

        dataSet.Tables["Person"].Rows.Add("Mr", "John",  "Smith");
        dataSet.Tables["Address"].Rows.Add("Street", "Suburb", "1234");
        dataSet.Tables["Address"].Rows[0].SetParentRow(dataSet.Tables["Person"].Rows[0]);

        return dataSet.GetXml();
```

This returns the following XML:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Person>
    <Ttl>Mr</Ttl>
    <Fore>John</Fore>
    <Sur>Smith</Sur>
    <Address>
      <Line_1>Street</Line_1>
      <Line_2>Suburb</Line_2>
      <PostCode>1234</PostCode>
    </Address>
  </Person>
</NewDataSet>
```

How can I preserve the order of the elements to satisfy the XSD validation?

Comment: `<xsd:sequence>` does enforce the order of the elements, `<xs:all>` does not. Read about [in this SO posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37831330/1305969). So it looks like you have to either adjust the XSD or the input XML.

Comment: @zx485 I am not in control of the xsd so cannot change xs:sequence to xs:all. What do you mean with the input XML?

Comment: XML order is not a requirement.  Is the xml failing a schema check?  ReadXml() method always fails when you have an XML file larger than four levels.  1) Root 2) Tables 3) Column Definitions 4) Row Data.  After 4 levels the DataSet creates fragmented tables that cannot be parsed.  I think if you look at your DataSet there is missing data which is in DataTable.

Comment: @jdweng Yes it's failing a schema check. xs:sequence elements require the elements in the right order. With the above code you can see it failing with just one level deep. There is no missing data.

Comment: The error is with Loading Data : "dataset, loading data into the dataset,"  You are loading the data in the wrong order.  The tags FORE and SUR is being loaded before ADDRESS instead of after ADDRESS.  Either change the XSD or change the order you load FORE and SUR.

Comment: @jdweng Changing the order that you load the data makes no difference. You can run and update this exact code above to see. If I'm missing something please provide the updated code in an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: You do not have the code posted that loaded the DataSet.  Where is code that does "loading data into the dataset"?

Comment: @jdweng It's there, just below the xsd definition. Scroll down on the code section.

Comment: You have a conflict between the schema and the xml.  You have one row of the table Person with the columns Mr John Smith.  You have a row in the Address table with columns Street Suburb 123.  How can John Smith be both before the address and after the address?  The xml shows John Smith before the address while the schema shows John Smith after the address.  John Smith cannot be both before and after the address at the same time.

Comment: @jdweng That's exactly the point of the question. I do not personally generate the xml, the dataset exports that xml with the `GetXml()` function and the elements are not in the order that the xsd requires. How do we get it to export in the right order?

Comment: The XSD is wrong.  It is impossible with the XSD to get an xml to pass the schema check.  You have two Data Tables (Person and Address)and the schema wants to split the data in the Person table so some of the info is before the Address table and other data after the Address table.  Or you do not use the DataSet method to read the Xml.

Comment: @jdweng That is just not true. If you move the Address element to between the Ttl element and the Fore element the xml passes the XSD validation. All I need is for the DataSet to export the data according to the same schema it was built with, i.e. following the constraints of the xs:sequence element.

I don't think you're understanding the problem and this conversation is not productive. Thank you for attempting to help.

Comment: You are saying the same thing I'm saying.  You have a row in the person table that has to be split so some of the data is before the address and some of the data after the address.  The row cannot be split using the DataSet method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by writing my own custom converter class that uses the xsd as a reference to generate the final xml. Something similar to this:

```
public class DataSetToSchemaBasedXmlConverter : IConvert<DataSet, XmlDocument>
{
    private readonly XmlSchema _schema;

    public DataSetToSchemaBasedXmlConverter(XmlSchema schema)
    {
        _schema = schema;
    }

    public XmlDocument Convert(DataSet dataSet)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();

        // Traverse through xsd elements and create corresponding 
        // xml elements based on the dataset values.

        return doc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I'm fairly confident preserving schema-defined element ordering not possible with the `DataSet` class in .NET.

According to Microsoft, [from this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/dataset-and-xmldatadocument-synchronization):

> ...If the DataSet is populated from an XML document using ReadXml, when the data is written back as an XML document using `WriteXml` it may differ dramatically from the original XML document. **This is because the DataSet does not maintain formatting, such as white space, or hierarchical information, such as element order, from the XML document.** The DataSet also does not contain elements from the XML document that were ignored because they did not match the schema of the Dataset.

I've bolded the relevant sentence. If you also decompile the `WriteXml()` and `GetXml()` methods of the `DataSet` class (since you're using `GetXml()`), they both use the same internal `XmlDataTreeWriter` class to write output XML, so presumably the above applies to your case as well. The above documentation page also mentions that one should prefer using `XmlDataDocument` but just keep in mind, that is a deprecated class.

Also with regards to the first part of your question:

> I am loading an XSD file into an empty dataset, loading data into the dataset, and then writing an XML file with that dataset.

If that is all there is, I recommend that since you already have an XML Schema, that you use a code generation strategy that generates C# model classes ahead of time.

A tool like [LinqToXsd](https://github.com/mamift/LinqToXsdCore), which was a Microsoft-written tool that they open-sourced, will take a schema, and generate C# classes that you can then program against (it's .NET Core/.NET and .NET Framework compatible). I tried using it for your schema, and ended up with code like this (I've left out the generated code because it's too long for an SO post):

```
var p = new Person();
p.Ttl = "Mr";
p.Fore.Add("John");
p.Sur = "Smith";

p.Address = new Default.Person.AddressLocalType()
{
    Line_1 = { "Street 1" },
    Line_2 = { "Suburb" }
};
```

Note that the call to set `Address` is last in C# code, but when you convert it back to XML by calling `p.ToString()`, it will preserve the ordering defined in the schema (which is `Address` as element 2 under the `Person` element):

```
<Person>
  <Ttl>Mr</Ttl>
  <Address>
    <Line_1>Street 1</Line_1>
    <Line_2>Suburb</Line_2>
  </Address>
  <Fore>John</Fore>
  <Sur>Smith</Sur>
</Person>
```

I recommend using `LinqToXsd` as it has much better support for complex types over **xsd.exe**. Unless, of course you have no choice but to use `DataSet` for legacy reasons.

Comment: Thank you for this, the Microsoft quote answers the question for my case. Unfortunately I am forced to use a dataset and cannot create strongly typed classes, so I have resorted to writing my own converter class that uses the xsd as a reference to generate the final xml.